# Strange behaviour when switching buffers in vim (syntax highlighting and keymaps cease to work until .vimrc source)

Tags: vimrc, buffers, plugin-airline

I have set up the following list of commands to switch buffers: (in a `.vim` file i `source` from my `.vimrc` to keep it organised)

```
:noremap <C-Left> <esc>:bnext<CR>                                                                                                                                                     
:noremap <C-Right> <esc>:bprev<CR>                                                                                                                                                    
:noremap <C-x> <esc>:bd<CR>
```

*(I am using airline to see buffers in top row when there aren't multiple tabs.)*
And whenever I switch to a different buffer, on some occasions (I have noticed this mostly when editing .dotfiles), on switching back the initial buffer loses all colour.
Also, these bindings have since recently stopped working and show an                                                                                                                     `E338: Could not find definition.`                                                                                                                                                           error.
However, entering `:map <C-Left>` only outputs my mapping and nothing else, and again, this used to work before. When I map the command to a different sequence, say `<escape><left>`, it does mostly end up working, though. (I would still prefer this one for convenience.)
What gives?
(i am using `Gnome terminal (xterm)` + `tmux`)

**Additional information:** I have recently accidentally replaced my                                                                                                                              `/etc/bin/bash/`                                                                                                                                                                         with a single file and am experiencing some other strange behaviour with `vim` and `xterm` ever since. I have, however, never found out if the folder is supposed to be useful in any way and am not currently in a spot to reinstall my whole system. What should the folder contain on a healthy system?

**My .vim folder is to be found on my git repo [OndraX/MyVimDir](http://github.com/OndraX/MyVimDir).** 
 *(personal and for convenience, but feel no need to waste one of five slots on hiding it)*